# glCreateShader causes segmentation fault

Tags: opengl, sfml

I can't create a shader when trying to use shaders with sfml. The function glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); causes a segmentation fault. At first I googled it and found that it does that when the program does not have an opengl context. I tried SDL first but the poor documentation and "look at the header to know what to do" made me go for sfml

the code that causes the seg fault is bellow

```
    sf::Window App(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML OpenGL");

// Set color and depth clear value
glClearDepth(1.f);
glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);

// Enable Z-buffer read and write
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

// Setup a perspective projection
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

GLuint vertShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    //...
```

I'm including glew, gl.h, sfml-window, sfml-system, using opengl 2.1 on gcc linux.

What is missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're not checking OpenGL extensions, version, or etc.

```
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (err != GLEW_OK)
  exit(1); // or handle the error in a nicer way
if (!GLEW_VERSION_2_1)  // check that the machine supports the 2.1 API.
  exit(1); // or handle the error in a nicer way
```

This code needs to happen **after** creating the OpenGL context, but **before** using any potentially-not-existing functions.  More details on the [GLEW web page](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html)

Comment: glewInit returns 1 and glewGetString(err) returns "1.6.0"

Comment: that '1' return is GLEW_ERROR_NO_GL_VERSION.  It means that you don't have an OpenGL context.  Don't pass 'err' into glewGetString() -- pass it into glewGetErrorString() to get the printable version of the error message.

Comment: shouldn't the context be created when I call the constructor to sf::Window?

Comment: I don't know SFML, so don't know what you need to do to make the OpenGL context in that library (maybe someone else will be able to post another answer, filling in that knowledge?)  But I do use GLEW a lot, and the error value you posted means that at the time when you called glewInit(), no OpenGL context had been created.  So presumably there's something else you need to do?

Comment: I followed SFML tutorial on their website. I'll accept your answer but how you create an opengl context? I'm having no luck with SDL as well

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Didn't know that glew was necessary when creating a rendering context outside of glut

Comment: @EmmettJ.Butler glew isn't technically necessary (that is, there are other ways to accomplish what glew does).  My answer was stating that if you are going to use glew, then you need to create an OpenGL context before initialising glew;  it won't work if you try to initialise glew before creating the OpenGL context.